# Why can't I find libpython2.7.so or libpython2.7.so.1.0

Tags: python, centos, shared-libraries

I am installing Python on CentOS 6.5 like this:

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
tar xf Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2 
cd Python-2.7.3
./configure –prefix=/usr/local
make
make altinstall
```

This installs python2.7 fine, however, I can't seem to locate `libpython2.7.so` or `libpython2.7.so.1.0` on the system.

I need the `.so` for other things like `mod_wsgi`

Is there some flag I'm missing while installing python?